# fscanf crashing the program as it tries to scan in rest of text file

Tags: c, file, dynamic-memory-allocation, scanf

I have a text file named dictionary, on the first line it is an int that tells us how many words are in the dictionary. After the first line it is a subsequent series of lines with a word on each.

For some reason fscanf reads in the first line (the integer) with no problem but as I try to read in the string with the loop it crashes right then and there. I am unsure what the error as visual studios just gives me an unhandled exception in some other file (I assume this is the code for the fscanf function).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXWORDLENGTH 19
const int DX_SIZE = 8;
const int DX[] = {-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1};
const int DY[]= {-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1};

char** storeDictionary();

int main(void){
char** dictionary;
dictionary = storeDictionary();
system("pause");
    return 0;
}

char** storeDictionary(){
    int i;
    int j;
    FILE *fp;
    char** dictionary;
    fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    int amountOfWords;
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &amountOfWords);
    dictionary = calloc(amountOfWords, sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORDLENGTH; i++){
        dictionary[i] = calloc(MAXWORDLENGTH, sizeof(char*));
    }
    if (dictionary == NULL){
        printf("Allocation failed");

    }
    for(i=0; i< amountOfWords; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < MAXWORDLENGTH; j++){
            fscanf(fp, "%s", dictionary[i]);

        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for(i =0; i<amountOfWords;i++){
        printf("%s",dictionary[i]);
        printf("\n");

    }

    return dictionary;

}
```

Also I may be dynamically allocating wrong, but I've tried various ways and get the same crash at the fscanf in the loop.

Comment: You should be checking the return values from `fopen()`, `fscanf()` and `calloc()` to ensure you aren't getting premature failures.  You check `dictionary`, but far too late to do any good.  You're also not allocating enough space if `amountOfWords` (better termed `numberOfWords`) is smaller than `MAXWORDLENGTH`, and you're allocating 4 or 8 times as much space as you need for each string.  If that's fixed, your code is only safe if your dictionary doesn't include 'antidisestablishmentarianism' (28 letters) or 'floccinaucinihilipilification' (29) or 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious' (34).

Comment: Also, when debugging this, you should print out each word as it is read in, which would tell you more about when the crash occurs.  Make sure you terminate each printing operation with a newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah okay I understand it all, thanks I'll make sure to always check the return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong loop bound here:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXWORDLENGTH; i++){
    dictionary[i] = calloc(MAXWORDLENGTH, sizeof(char*));
}
```

Change it to:

```
for (i = 0; i < amountOfWords; i++){
    dictionary[i] = calloc(MAXWORDLENGTH, sizeof(char*));
}
```

Jonathan Leffler also points out that the size used in these `calloc` calls is wrong.  `sizeof(char *)` should be `sizeof(char)` in those calls.

Of course, you need to guarantee that each string is no more than `MAXWORDLENGTH - 1` characters long.

Comment: It's also only allocating enough length for a `char *`, not `MAXWORDLENGTH` bytes.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a good pointer (although it will end up allocating more than it should).

Comment: I got caught by `calloc()` vs `malloc()` — your analysis (over-allocation, not under-allocation) is correct.